# layout above recyclerview of the screen moves up when keyboard is displayed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

RecyclerView have EditText in it and when I click on EditText my RecyclerView moves up but problem is layout above RecyclerView also moves up and doesn't scroll down,so it won't be entirely visble unless keyboard goes,though RecyclerView scroll properly.In manifest i set android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
My layout snippet

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="14dp">

      <!--  <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_rec"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:id="@+id/linear"
                android:orientation="vertical">
    -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/sender"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/sender_info"
                        style="@style/MyTextViewStyleRed"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:text="Heading"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/receiver" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/user_info"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/sender_info">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/linear1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/txt_cust_id"
                                style="@style/MyTextViewStyleBlack"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="name"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/home_size" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/txt_mobile_number"
                                style="@style/MyTextViewStyleBlack"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="email"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/home_size" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/txt_amount_dialog"
                                style="@style/MyTextViewStyleBlack"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="comment"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/home_size" />


                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/linear2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/linear1"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/colon_id"
                                style="@style/MyTextViewStyleBlack"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text=":"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/home_size" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/colon_mobile"
                                style="@style/MyTextViewStyleBlack"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text=":"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/home_size" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/colon_amount"
                                style="@style/MyTextViewStyleBlack"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text=":"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/home_size" />

                        </LinearLayout>


                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/l1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linear2"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <HorizontalScrollView
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
                                android:scrollbarSize="2px"
                                android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@drawable/thumb_scroll">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tv_name"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                                    android:text="abc"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/home_size" />
                            </HorizontalScrollView>
                            <!--<TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_name"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:ellipsize="end"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:text="sankalp sankalp(9987345231))"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />-->

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_kyc_status"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="xyz"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/home_size" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_monthly_limit"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="250000"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/home_size" />


                        </LinearLayout>

                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <!--<Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_transfer"
                    style="@style/MyTextViewStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/sender"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_maroon"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_transfer"
                    android:drawablePadding="3dp"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:minHeight="0dp"
                    android:minWidth="0dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Add Receiver"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/home_size" />-->
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_transfer"
                    style="@style/MyTextViewStyleButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/sender"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_maroon"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Add"
                   />


                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/btn_transfer"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"></View>
           <!-- </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/view"
            android:transcriptMode="normal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_empty"
            style="@style/MyTextViewStyleRed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:text="@string/NoInternet"
            android:visibility="gone"></TextView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try to use : `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` instead.

Comment: Thanks alot it worked,tried all combination before none worked

Comment: One more thing, when i scroll RecyclerView edittext  loses focus, value in editext is intact though

Answer (score 0):

Add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" to the activity tag on the manifest.xml